# GUI emacs: What Face Defines Overlay for Truncated Lines in Margin?

Tags: faces, overlays, customize-face

I am currently using the emacs GUI.

I have a custom theme defined for a particular buffer, but when the text runs over the line, an overlay takes over (presumably handling truncation) in the margins. I'm having trouble finding the name of this overlay so that I can create a custom face for it. I cannot find face at point for obvious reasons. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may find and alter it? Perhaps using face at point with the mouse?

Fringes are currently off (fringe-mode returns 0), but I have modified the marigin-widths.

I have included an image illustrating the problem.

[image]

Comment: The dollar sign is probably a glyph created, in part, by `SET_GLYPH_FROM_CHAR (glyph, '$')` in `xdisp.c`.  Some display table entries containing glyphs can receive face/colors in the GUI version of Emacs, but I've never researched or experimented with terminal Emacs in that regard.  When the fringe is active, Emacs uses bitmap images to show termination/continuation and those can receive color as well.  Consider editing the question to  indicate whether this is terminal or GUI version of Emacs that is being run, and whether fringes are turned off/on.

Comment: Thanks, @lawlist, it's been updated. Where would I go about looking for these tables?

Comment: Without fringes in GUI Emacs:  I was able to change the character to something else, but I did not have any luck changing color.  `(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'truncation ?%)` or if a `buffer-display-table` is buffer-local, then `(set-display-table-slot buffer-display-table 'truncation ?%)`.  I did not have any luck modifying the entry of the `buffer-display-table` using: `(setq buffer-display-table (let ((display-table (make-display-table)) (termination (make-vector 1 (make-glyph-code ?% 'font-lock-function-name-face)))) (aset display-table 0 termination) display-table))`